# CSS in blueprintjs doesn't load correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, blueprintjs

I'm using Filter Input from blueprintjs in a reactjs project, but the style doesn't load correctly, here's my code:

`Assigning.jsx`

```
import './Assigning.scss';
export default class Assigning extends Component {
render() {
        return (
<div className="bp3-input-group modifier">
                        <span className="bp3-icon bp3-icon-filter" />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="bp3-input modifier"
                            placeholder="Filter histogram..."
                        />
                    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`Assigning.scss`

```
@import '~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css';
@import '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

is `~` character required at the beginning of import ?
It works with me with the following imports

```
import "@blueprintjs/table/lib/css/table.css";
import "@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
```

The full code for the component is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="bp3-input-group modifier">
        <span className="bp3-icon bp3-icon-filter" />
        <input
            type="text"
            className="bp3-input modifier"
            placeholder="Filter histogram..."
        />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

I got the following output
[image: Output of the above sample code]